# Creating custom directory in iOS Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to create a custom directory using following snippet, that I essentially translated from a working Obj-C code for the same app.

```
class func pathToConfigFolder() -> String {
    let urls: [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let libraryPath: String = urls.last!
    let configFolder: String = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: libraryPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(".conf").absoluteString

    var directory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(true)
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(configFolder, isDirectory: &directory) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(configFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print(" Error thrown... \(error)")
        }
    }
    return configFolder
}
```

But the code fails with following error.

```
Error thrown... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x17526f4c0 {NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/44D90AEB-DD7A-4C8C-9AD0-2665147BAAEC/Library/conf, NSUnderlyingError=0x174054c40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

I have tried both on device and simulator running iOS 9.

**EDIT**
Objective-C Code

```
+ (NSString*) pathToConfigFolder
{
    NSArray *urls = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,
                                                        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryPath = [urls lastObject];

    NSString *configFolder = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".conf"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if ( ! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:configFolder]) {

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:configFolder
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:&error];
    }
    return configFolder;
}
```

Comment: Attach the Obj-C code, maybe we can spot the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
let libraryPath: String = urls.last!
let configFolder: String = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: libraryPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(".conf").absoluteString
```

The `absoluteString` method returns the entire URL as a string, so your `configFolder` is `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/44D90AEB-DD7A-4C8C-9AD0-2665147BAAEC/Library/conf`. That is, it **includes** the `file://` and is therefore not a valid file path suitable for use with the `NSFileManager` methods you use it with.

Changing those lines to look like this would fix the problem:

```
let libraryPath: NSString = urls.last!
let configFolder = libraryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(".conf")
```

I'm using `NSString` here because that's where `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is defined.

Comment: When I used `String` the compiler complained that `stringByAppendingPathComponent` didn't exist.

Comment: The code I posted does not use URLs, it uses file paths. I left the misnamed `urls` variable alone because changing it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: @LeoDabus please do feel free to write your own answer to this question.

Comment: thank you so much, it did the trick. Had to cast String to NSString to use that method. :)